# load ajax contents inside the fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

Working onjquery stuff, i working on the following code and it works great, i want to add a fancybox to it, i mean rather than opening in same page, i want the contents to be loaded in the fancybox:

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click','#table td a', function(e) {
            var hcall = e.currentTarget.toString();
            var cURL = hcall;
            ax();
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'mypage.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(cURL),
                    crossDomain : true,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");},
                    success: function(data){
                        cx();
                        $('#table').html(data);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
});
```

with fancybox i am trying like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#table td a', function(e) {
                var hcall = e.currentTarget.toString();
                var cURL = hcall;
                ax();
                $.fancybox({
            'width':800,
            'height':650,
            'type':'iframe',
            'autoScale':'true',
            openEffect: 'elastic',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            aftershow: function() {
                $.ajax({
                        url: 'mypage.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(cURL),
                        crossDomain : true,
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");},
                        success: function(data){
                            cx();
                            $('#table').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
     }
    });
});
```

but it does seesm to work, it loads the fancybox and the new page also and the fancybox gives 404 error. a object is passed to the url. i am bit confused here

Comment: Could you please explain _it loads the fancybox and the new page also and the fancybox gives 404 error_  better? The page is loaded but it returns a 404?

Comment: i m not sure but it gives error like https://mywebsite.com:443/folder/folder2/[object Object]

Comment: "it gives error" but where? In the developer console? Is that the error message in the console : `mywebsite.com:443/folder/folder2/[object Object]` ? Doesn't make much sense

Comment: yes, in console it gives this, i am lost

Comment: i have not used the href attribute of fancybox, it that could be the issue

Comment: Is "mypage.php" found? What is the response from this file when it is called? what if you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: this page is found when it loads it itself in new window, as i said above it opens a fancybox and it opens new page too

Comment: Sorry but I don't even understand what you're trying to explain. I don't understand  `it loads it itself in new window`, or `it opens new page too`. I guess you should just read better the "ajax" part of the fancybox documentation :  http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions The instruction is `.fancybox({type: 'ajax'})` and you're currently not using it.

Comment: ok, the way i am implementing might be wrong, you please let me know how can i call that ajax inisde the fancybox, it should load fancybox and then this ajax contents inside that

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it the other way around : call Ajax first and then display the *response* in fancybox within the `success` setting like :

```
$(document).on('click', '#table td a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hcall = e.currentTarget.toString();
    var cURL = hcall;
    ax();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mypage.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(cURL),
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            cx();
            // create a new HTML element and place response on it
            var _content = $('<div />', {
                id: "newId"
            }).html(data);
            $.fancybox({
                content: _content, // this is where you display ajax result
                // other API options
                width: 800,
                height: 650,
                // type: 'iframe', // you don't need this, is AJAX remember?
                autoScale: 'true',
                openEffect: 'elastic',
                closeEffect: 'elastic'
            }); // fancybox
        }
    }); // ajax
});
```

**Notice** we are creating a new HTML element and adding the *response* to it using the `.html()` method, but it not may be necessary. In most cases (depending on the *type* of ajax *response*) you could pass the *response* as first parameter in the fancybox method like :

```
$.ajax({
    // Ajax params
    success: function (data) {
        cx();
        $.fancybox(data, {
            // API options
        });
    }
}); // ajax
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**